# Creating ppp objects with lapply (package spatstat)

Tags: r, lapply, spatstat

My ultimate goal is to calculate Clark-Evans-Index (`clarkevans.test`) for a list of data frames using package spatstat.

So I have a list of my point data:

```
points.li <- list(structure(list(x.n = c(-1.37977544977995, 0.0787053126116266, 
-6.50583075192879, -9.17021249875416, -19.4146851390704, -22.7380870106472, 
-20.3267566111816, -15.7328116296655, -8.74750043303314, -11.8963575795747
), y.n = c(13.1276911114957, 2.22311850078447, 9.48873515598742, 
2.7986686485412, 2.56632386092958, -0.757078010647191, 6.88269379207495, 
11.5304629645448, 19.131978467755, 28.8757897612883)), row.names = 1098:1107, class = "data.frame", .Names = c("x.n", 
"y.n")), structure(list(x.n = c(0.104714438623701, 1.93357872460516, 
1.51117985822383, 4.47756948027361, 0.710996014054978, -0.727469791776916, 
0.694499984379773, 2.88088318987335, -5.90066975026119, -11.3699018974284
), y.n = c(-5.99908617093835, -9.09677268682439, -12.3075722803524, 
-16.7105167948009, -16.2844860117843, -13.8809505330886, -19.88787745768, 
-20.4985490229505, -14.9797228445106, -17.1780479345837)), row.names = 108:117, class = "data.frame", .Names = c("x.n", 
"y.n")))

> points.li
[[1]]
              x.n       y.n
1098  -1.37977545 13.127691
1099   0.07870531  2.223119
1100  -6.50583075  9.488735
1101  -9.17021250  2.798669
1102 -19.41468514  2.566324
1103 -22.73808701 -0.757078
1104 -20.32675661  6.882694
1105 -15.73281163 11.530463
1106  -8.74750043 19.131978
1107 -11.89635758 28.875790

[[2]]
            x.n        y.n
108   0.1047144  -5.999086
109   1.9335787  -9.096773
110   1.5111799 -12.307572
111   4.4775695 -16.710517
112   0.7109960 -16.284486
113  -0.7274698 -13.880951
114   0.6945000 -19.887877
115   2.8808832 -20.498549
116  -5.9006698 -14.979723
117 -11.3699019 -17.178048
```

and a list of the plot coordinates:

```
ref.li <- list(structure(list(x.ref = c(-51.957519, -44.640527, 24.976003, 
17.659011), y.ref = c(39.756418, -29.860112, -22.54312, 47.07341
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("x.ref", 
"y.ref")), structure(list(x.ref = c(15.613798, -52.306902, -35.372372, 
32.548328), y.ref = c(40.306747, 23.372217, -44.548483, -27.613953
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("x.ref", 
"y.ref")))

> ref.li
[[1]]
      x.ref     y.ref
1 -51.95752  39.75642
2 -44.64053 -29.86011
3  24.97600 -22.54312
4  17.65901  47.07341

[[2]]
      x.ref     y.ref
1  15.61380  40.30675
2 -52.30690  23.37222
3 -35.37237 -44.54848
4  32.54833 -27.61395
```

I created a list of `owin` objects:

```
library(spatstat)
bound.li <- lapply(ref.li, function(x) {owin(poly = list(x = x$x.ref, y = x$y.ref))})

> bound.li
[[1]]
window: polygonal boundary
enclosing rectangle: [-51.95752, 24.976] x [-29.86011, 47.07341] units

[[2]]
window: polygonal boundary
enclosing rectangle: [-52.3069, 32.54833] x [-44.54848, 40.30675] units
```

And now I'd like to create the `ppp` objects:

```
pattern.li <- lapply(points.li, function(x) {ppp(x$x.n, x$y.n, window=bound.li)})
```

resulting in:

```
Error in verifyclass(window, "owin") : 
  argument ‘window’ is not of class ‘owin’
```

I don't know if the problem is using a list of owin objects or my incorrect use of lapply with the ppp function as I need to refer to two lists here but don't know how. Any hint how to solve this?

(*edit*) I also tried

```
mapply(function(x, y) {ppp(x$x.n, x$y.n, window=y)}, x=points.li, y=bound.li)
```

but that does not return a list of ppp objects..

Comment: Once you use one of the solutions below you might want to add the spatstat class `solist` (spatial object list) to the result (assuming you named the list `pattern.li`): `pattern.li <- as.solist(pattern.li)`. For instance it automatically makes a layout for you when you plot the entire list of point patterns: `plot(pattern.li)`.

Comment: @EgeRubak thanks, that's very interesting and useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the whole list of `owin` objects to the `window` parameter in `ppp`. You can use `Map` instead to iterate over both lists simultaneously. When you attempted `mapply` it automatically simplified the result. You can also use the `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` argument for `mapply`:

```
Map(function(x, y) {ppp(x$x.n, x$y.n, window=y)}, x=points.li, y=bound.li)
#[[1]]
#Planar point pattern: 10 points
#window: polygonal boundary
#enclosing rectangle: [-51.95752, 24.976] x [-29.86011, 47.07341] units
#
#[[2]]
#Planar point pattern: 10 points
#window: polygonal boundary
#enclosing rectangle: [-52.3069, 32.54833] x [-44.54848, 40.30675] units
```

Answer (score 3):

Your last suggestion almost works. You just need the argument `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`:

```
mapply(function(x, y) {ppp(x$x.n, x$y.n, window=y)}, x=points.li, y=bound.li, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Alternatively you can call the function `as.ppp` with `X` as your `data.frame` of point coordinates and `W` as your `owin` object:

```
mapply(as.ppp, X = points.li, W = bound.li, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: The approach by @pierre-lafortune using `Map` seems more modern in the spirit of functional programming, so I have also upvoted that. Actually it seems `Map` in R is just a wrapper to `mapply` avoiding the simplify argument, so you were really on the right track.